# invoke a command when clicking a button using Event trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I would like to call a method when clicking on a `Button`. Here is what I have done. In the XAML, I have

```
<Button Content="HELLO" Width="40" Height="20">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding InteractionCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

and in the ViewModel, I have

```
class MainWindowViewModel : Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase
{
    public ICommand InteractionCommand { get; private set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.InteractionCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnInteraction);
    }

    public void OnInteraction(object obj)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me where I'm wrong because this does not work.
Thank you.

P:S: I know that I can bind the command inside the `Button` without using the event trigger.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an event trigger?

Comment: I'am not sure if it is the best way to do that but I have two button A and B binding on a method that opens the same flyout which contains a button C. The button C has a different action depending on the button that called it. On the event trigger I would like to set a property to "FromA" of "FromB". The command on buttons A ans B is _Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.OpenDrawerCommand}_ so I can't set the property here.

Comment: @mm8 the link is done in the XAML _<Window ....   d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type vm:MainWindowViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}">_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work just fine provided that you have set the `DataContext` of the `Button` to an instance of your view model class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

The following only sets a *design time* `DataContext` that is not applied when you actually run the application:

```
<Window .... d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type vm:MainWindowViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}">
```

It's only used in the context of the Visual Studio designer.

Comment: Thank you. Just for my information. what is the difference between your set of the DataContext and writing  _<Window.DataContext><vm:MainWindowViewModel/></Window.DataContext>_ in the XAML ? Both seems to works.

Comment: Nothing really. My approach sets the same DataContext programmatically. You can do the same in XAML provided that you don't need to inject the view model class with any parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a nice day.